# Why is mapStateToProps being called 2 times before componentWillReceiveProps?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have an action file, which calls two actions in a row:

```
export const navigate =  url => dispatch => {
  dispatch(actions.navigateToUrl(url));
  dispatch(actions.clearNavigateToUrl());
};
```

The update to the store hits a connect function in one of my `Component`s:

```
export default connect(state => ({
    url: state.navigate.url
  })
})(withRouter(Navigate));
```

And then I have a `componentWillReceiveProps` that should be hit each time the `state` is updated.

The `mapStateToProps` is hit 2 times in a row, but my `componentWillReceiveProps` is only hit the second time, like there is some kind of batching.  I thought there was only batching in `setState`.

I can add a `setTimeout` with no wait time around the second `dispatch` in the `action` and then I hit the `componentWillReceiveProps` both times:

```
export const navigate =  url => dispatch => {
  dispatch(actions.navigateToUrl(url));
  setTimeout(dispatch(actions.clearNavigateToUrl()));
};
```

But obviously this isn't wanted and I was just testing to see if it was a timing issue.

What do I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

React-Redux's `connect` function ultimately does use `setState()` to signal React that the wrapper component needs to re-render.  It will also re-run your `mapState` function any time the root state object has been updated.  So yes, that sounds like expected behavior.  Your `mapState` will run for both dispatched actions, `connect` will internally call `setState()` both times, and React will batch up the updates and only re-render the component once.

Comment: So other than using a `setTimeout`, what is the best way to handle this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? Why do you need both changes to trigger `componentWillReceiveProps`?